# Please give me reasons why my slider/slideshow wont work on https

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, https, web

i have a site that runs perfectly on "http" but when in "https" the slider won't work.
i want to know what possible reasons that my script won't work on "https".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                            $('#CU3ER7').cu3er({
                                vars: {
                                    xml_location: "/wp-content/uploads/wpcu3er/3344/CU3ER_Services Slider 2012(6)/CU3ER-config.xml",
                                    xml_encoded: '%3Cdata%3E%3Clicence%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B+%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flicence%3E%3Clicence%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B+%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flicence%3E%3Clicence%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B+%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flicence%3E%3Clicence%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B+%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flicence%3E%3Clicence%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B+%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flicence%3E%3Cproject_settings%3E%3Cwidth%3E960%3C%2Fwidth%3E%3Cheight%3E394%3C%2Fheight%3E%3C%2Fproject_settings%3E%3Csettings%3E%3Cbackground%3E%3Ccolor+transparent%3D%22true%22%3E0xffffff%3C%2Fcolor%3E%3Cimage+use_image%3D%22true%22+align_to%3D%22stage%22+align_pos%3D%22TC%22+x%3D%220%22+y%3D%220%22+scaleX%3D%221%22+scaleY%3D%221%22%3E%3Curl%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B1_okvir6.png%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Furl%3E%3C%2Fimage%3E%3C%2Fbackground%3E%3Cfolder_images%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fwpcu3er%2F3344%2FCU3ER_Services+Slider+2012%286%29%2Fimages%2F%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Ffolder_images%3E%3Cfolder_fonts%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fwpcu3er%2F3344%2FCU3ER_Services+Slider+2012%286%29%2Ffonts%2F%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Ffolder_fonts%3E%3C%2Fsettings%3E%3Cdefaults%3E%3Cslide+time%3D%225%22+color%3D%220x000000%22+transparent%3D%22false%22%3E%3Clink+target%3D%22_blank%22+%2F%3E%3Cdescription%3E%3Clink+target%3D%22_blank%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdescription%3E%3Cimage+align_pos%3D%22MC%22+x%3D%220%22+y%3D%220%22+scaleX%3D%228.27%22+scaleY%3D%223.54%22+fit%3D%22dafault%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fslide%3E%3Ctransition+type%3D%223D%22+columns%3D%223%22+rows%3D%223%22+type2D%3D%22slide%22+flipAngle%3D%22180%22+flipOrder%3D%2245%22+flipShader%3D%22none%22+flipOrderFromCenter%3D%22false%22+flipDirection%3D%22left%22+flipColor%3D%220x878787%22+flipBoxDepth%3D%2210%22+flipDepth%3D%22300%22+flipEasing%3D%22Sine.easeOut%22+flipDuration%3D%22.6%22+flipDelay%3D%22.15%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefaults%3E%3Cslides+align_pos%3D%22MC%22+x%3D%220%22+y%3D%22-19%22+width%3D%22800%22+height%3D%22300%22%3E%3Cslide+time%3D%223%22+use_image%3D%22true%22%3E%3Curl%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B1_simple_img_1.jpg%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Furl%3E%3Cimage+align_pos%3D%22MC%22+fit%3D%22dafault%22+x%3D%220%22+y%3D%220%22+scaleX%3D%220.85%22+scaleY%3D%221%22+%2F%3E%3Clink+target%3D%22_self%22%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fddwenterprises.com%2Fweb-design%2F%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flink%3E%3C%2Fslide%3E%3Ctransition+columns%3D%225%22+rows%3D%221%22+flipOrder%3D%220%22+flipShader%3D%22flat%22+flipDirection%3D%22right%22+%2F%3E%3Cslide+time%3D%223%22+use_image%3D%22true%22%3E%3Curl%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bsimple_img_2.jpg%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Furl%3E%3Cimage+align_pos%3D%22MC%22+fit%3D%22dafault%22+x%3D%220%22+y%3D%220%22+scaleX%3D%220.85%22+scaleY%3D%221%22+%2F%3E%3Clink+target%3D%22_self%22%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fddwenterprises.com%2Fidentity-branding%2F%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flink%3E%3Cdescription%3E%3Clink%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fgetcu3er.com%2Fjavascript%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flink%3E%3C%2Fdescription%3E%3C%2Fslide%3E%3Ctransition+columns%3D%2210%22+rows%3D%221%22+flipAngle%3D%2290%22+flipOrder%3D%220%22+flipShader%3D%22flat%22+flipDirection%3D%22up%22+flipDuration%3D%220.4999999999999999%22+%2F%3E%3Cslide+time%3D%223%22+use_image%3D%22true%22%3E%3Curl%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bsocial_marketing.png%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Furl%3E%3Cimage+align_pos%3D%22MC%22+fit%3D%22dafault%22+x%3D%220%22+y%3D%220%22+scaleX%3D%220.85%22+scaleY%3D%221%22+%2F%3E%3Clink+target%3D%22_self%22%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fddwenterprises.com%2Fsocial-marketing%2F%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flink%3E%3Cdescription%3E%3Clink%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fgetcu3er.com%2Ffeatures%2Fwpcu3er%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flink%3E%3C%2Fdescription%3E%3C%2Fslide%3E%3Ctransition+columns%3D%221%22+rows%3D%225%22+flipAngle%3D%2290%22+flipOrder%3D%2290%22+flipShader%3D%22flat%22+flipOrderFromCenter%3D%22true%22+flipDirection%3D%22left%2Cright%22+flipDuration%3D%220.7500000000000001%22+flipDelay%3D%220.3000000000000001%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fslides%3E%3C%2Fdata%3E',
                                    swf_location: 'http://ddwenterprises.com/wp-content/uploads/wpcu3er/CU3ER.swf?1373003827',
                                    css_location: 'http://ddwenterprises.com/wp-content/plugins/wpcu3er/css/CU3ER.css',
                                    js_location: 'http://ddwenterprises.com/wp-content/uploads/wpcu3er/jquery.cu3er.player.js?1373003827',
                                    width: '960',
                                    height: '394',
                                    force_javascript: false,
                                    force_flash: true
                                },
                                params: {
                                    wmode : 'transparent',
                                    allowScriptAccess: 'always'
                                },
                                attributes: {
                                    id:'CU3ER7',
                                    name:'CU3ER7'
                                }
                            });
                        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking out the http://ddwenterprises.com from your swf, css, and js locations?  If it's trying to load javascript dynamically it may be running into a cross site ajax error.  Domains, ports, and protocols must match and if you're trying to connect to http:// (port 80) on a https:// (port 443) page you'll get that error.

Comment: Even if it's your same domain it will fail because ports don't match.   Domains, ports, and protocols must match for an ajax request to work.  I am just shooting in the dark on this as I don't know how your script functions.  If you can give me a url for your page I can help diagnose it better.